# Need Ubuntu AMI of 10GB in size for Amazon AWS Free Usage Tier in Region "EU West"

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I've created an account on Amazon AWS because of their [Free Usage Tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) promotion. It allows for a "t1.micro" instance, free of charge for 1 year.

Unfortunately the "official" Ubuntu EBS images are 15 GB in size, and only 10 GB are free. And I know the monthly cost for the extra storage would be something like ~ 0.55 USD, but I was hoping for a free launch before investing in AWS, and I would rather spend that dollar on S3 :-)

So ... any Ubuntu EBS AMIs for t1.micro instances that are available in eu-west ?

Comment: Do questions like this belong on SO?

Comment: @darioo, do comments like yours belong on SO?

Comment: @Alexandru: sorry, didn't mean to be rude or anything. My first thought, when posting my comment, was: Perhaps this question would be better of on Serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

http://bitnami.org/stacks. Has free 10Gb EBS images that use Ubuntu

Comment: These require some work to get to vanilla Ubuntu though, like dropping the bitnami user, removing their app stack from /opt and reverting other customizations sprinkled through configuration files...

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who finds this via Google, try the official Ubuntu AMIs that work:
http://cloud.ubuntu.com/2010/11/using-ubuntu-images-on-aws-free-tier/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this website - http://thecloudmarket.com/owner/206029621532--amazon