# Amazon AWS EC2 Free Tier ubuntu desktop AMI

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

So I'm a bit of a newbie to linux and I wanted to check it out on amazons EC2 free tier.  Anyone know of an AMI that has ubuntu desktop on it that is in 10GB in size range for the free tier?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone who finds this via Google, try the official Ubuntu AMIs that work:
<s>http://cloud.ubuntu.com/2010/11/using-ubuntu-images-on-aws-free-tier/</s>

Updated link: https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/

Comment: Link is dead  It does not work anymore.

Comment: Snorberhuis, I updated the link

Answer (score 1):

@Adam

If those fail try this:

Find an AMI you like here
   http://bitnami.org/stacks

Then follow the instructions here
   http://bitnami.org/article/how-to-install-ubuntu-desktop-on-ec2-ebs

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try http://alestic.com/2008/04/ubuntu-desktop-ec2

It looks like there is another user that experienced this issue here.
[Need Ubuntu AMI of 10GB in size for Amazon AWS Free Usage Tier in Region "EU West"](https://serverfault.com/questions/197242/need-ubuntu-ami-of-10gb-in-size-for-amazon-aws-free-usage-tier-in-region-eu-west)

Comment: can't find an AMI that fits in the free tier